# Туториал по управлению пользователями на JSF

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf

Есть задача администрирования пользователей (их создание, удаление, редактирование, назначение ролей и т. д.) на основе двух таблиц, одна с пользователями, вторая с ролями.

Не могли бы подсказать хороший туториал или дать какие-то наводки по этой задаче.
В проекте используется JSF и Java EE7.

Comment: ищите реализацию CRUD на JSF

Answer (score 0):

Я для подобных задач на JSF использую [Apache Shiro](https://shiro.apache.org/). В качестве учебного примера можно рассмотреть вот [эту статью](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html)(на английском языке).

Или посмотреть примеры на [GitHub](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=JSF%20Shiro).

Answer (score 0):

[ВОТ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jYBUIGLf4lA&list=PLiJ76e8LBYQXWJyspvSpaO7m5BimBqIrH&index=7) Пожалуйста) Очень подробно рассказывает о ролевой модели и пилит ее на JSF в прямом эфире. Смотреть на скорости х2. Остальные плей листы его канала тоже полезные на тему JEE.